# Bootstrap 3 Carousel won't work. (Yes, I have jQuery loaded before Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm converting an application to Bootstrap 3.  Here's the code to my sample carousel page, in its entirety.  Yes, I have jQuery loaded before the Bootstrap.js gets loaded.  For whatever reason, the carousel simply will not work.  Specifically: the previous/next buttons don't work and the carousel doesn't automatically slide to the next slide.

Tested against:

- Safari 6.0.5
- Chrome 28.0.1500.95
- Firefox 23.0

...on Mac OS X 10.8.4

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="" alt-src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>

    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" type="text/css">

    <title>Carousel Test</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">

    <script>
        // Added this just so I didn't have to wait 5 seconds to see if the transition worked. //
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#Carousel').carousel({
                interval:   1000
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/Carousel/001.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/Carousel/002.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/Carousel/003.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anyone have an insight on why this is not working?

Comment: Does your console give you any errors?

Comment: Not on page load... and not when I click the previous and next buttons.  When I click the carousel indicators, I'm getting "TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'e.data("bs.carousel").to')" on bootstrap.min.js, line 6.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question. The problem I had was not loading jquery ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try one `carousel-inner` with multiple `item`s inside..

```
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img src="img/Carousel/001.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/Carousel/002.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img src="img/Carousel/003.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>

        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#Carousel" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/72622

Answer (score 3):

There's another mistake in this code which is that the carousel indicators aren't clickable. They should be links that take you to the appropriate panel.

You need to add a hashtag to the data target:

```
<li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
<li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is to help someone who was stuck like me despite writing all the code correctly. I was trying to find a error in the code but everything was fine. Then I checked my javascript files and noticed that somehow their type changed to **.js.txt** . So I just changed it to **.js** and it worked.

Happy coding !

Answer (score -1):

For the slider to work you must include:

```
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

at the bottom of your document(before body closing tag)

Comment: Down voting for two reasons:  1. The question is 2 years old.  2.  The bootstrap javascript is loaded on line 15.